# Can't connect to MySQL running on a Linux (ubuntu 16.04) virtual machine on Azure using my local laptop

Tags: mysql, azure, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I can connect to the virtual machine using SSH with PuTTY terminal emulator

[image]

---

Then with MySql server running on the virtual machine on the Azure cloud platform I Attempt a remote
connection to the MySQL database from my laptop using both MySQL and the MySQL workbench. Both
methods result in a can't connect status.

[image]

---

---

[image]

---

The user has all privileges assigned, the ip address is the same as I use in PuTTY and the port is correct.

---

In my Azure portal the security rules are set like the documentation say to:

[image]

---

This problem seems like a problem accepting my laptop's IP address. However, the security rules specify and IP address for a MySQL connection to the VM. Also no problem connecting with PuTTY.

I have no problem using SQL Workbench to connect to a pre-configured:
Azure Database for MySQL Server

Only when I am using a (raw) self-configured SQL Server on a Virtual Machine in Azure.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the service is up and running while you are trying to connect. I understand you locally can connect to it but may be have two screens open and check if status changes in between...
use following command to check service status:

`netstat -plan | grep :3306`

Once you have done that and still an issue please check that the config file in MySQL is configured to enable remote access. File located in the following directory.

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

you may find the following blog helpful. It has detail instructions.
https://bobcares.com/blog/cannot-connect-to-mysql-server-10060/